# How to Measure Lead Time for Order Delivery by Different Shipping Carriers using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, window-functions

I want to measure the lead time regarding orders delivery, from the shipping to the first attempt of delivery, in order to analyse the performance of different shipping carriers.

This is a sample for the carrier_id '08203F165768' from the source table ([WARS].[cust].[ORDER_STATUS_CARRIER]):

| REFERENCE_ID | CARRIER_ID | CARRIER_NAME | STATUS_CARRIER_ID | STATUS_CARRIER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CXEXP3688525 | 08203F165768 | MRW | 16 | 2023-03-24 06:57:00 |
| CXEXP3688525 | 08203F165768 | MRW | 91 | 2023-03-23 17:18:00 |
| CXEXP3688525 | 08203F165768 | MRW | 48 | 2023-03-22 10:14:00 |

I have the codes for each carrier about the first attempt to deliver so I created a temp table #first_attempt_to_deliver with all these codes and where I obtain this first attempt to deliver date (STATUS_CARRIER_DATE) and then it will be LEFT JOINED with the table that contains the data about orders, to create a new column.

```
--STATUS_CARRIER_IDs and STATUS_CARRIER_DATE with the first attempt to deliver by the carrier
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #first_attempt_to_deliver
SELECT 
    REFERENCE_ID
    ,CARRIER_ID
    ,STATUS_CARRIER_ID
    ,STATUS_CARRIER_DATE
INTO #first_attempt_to_deliver
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT
            REFERENCE_ID
            ,CARRIER_ID
            ,STATUS_CARRIER_ID
            ,STATUS_CARRIER_DATE
            , RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CARRIER_ID ORDER BY STATUS_CARRIER_DATE)
        FROM [WARS].[cust].[ORDER_STATUS_CARRIER] stat WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE STATUS_CARRIER_ID IN ('EMH','EMW','01','07','16','8','39','001','002','OFD','2','14','81','9301','91','92','SP_DSP')
        ) x 
        WHERE RowN = 1
```

**Result I'm obtaining:**

| ORDER_NR | SHIP_REFERENCE | SHIP_TRACKING_NR | SHIP_COMPANY | NEW_COLUMN_FIRST_ATTEMPT_DELIVER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SE2785386 | CXEXP3688525 | 08203F165768 | MRW | **2023-03-23 17:18:00.000** |

**Expected result:**

| ORDER_NR | SHIP_REFERENCE | SHIP_TRACKING_NR | SHIP_COMPANY | NEW_COLUMN_FIRST_ATTEMPT_DELIVER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SE2785386 | CXEXP3688525 | 08203F165768 | MRW | **2023-03-24 06:57:00** |

For the MRW carrier the code that is related with the first attempt of delivery is the code 16, but there are other codes for the same order, since the package goes through different stages (in preparation, shipped from the warehouse, etc) before it's in fact delivered by the carrier.

The problem is that one of these codes (the code 91) is the first attempt to deliver code for another carrier (SPRING) and since the first STATUS_CARRIER_DATE that happens first is the 2023-03-23 17:18:00, related with this code 91, on the temp table I get this date and should get the date 2023-03-24 06:57:00 related with STATUS_CARRIER_ID=16, for this order shipped by MRW.

I'm not sure if this could be solved using a CASE WHEN, I'm not figuring out how to do it.

But the idea would be:

1. When the carrier_name=MRW, the STATUS_CARRIER_DATE to be selected would be the the one related with STATUS_CARRIED_ID=16;
2. When the carrier_name=SPRING, the STATUS_CARRIER_DATE to be selected would be the one related with STATUS_CARRIED_ID=91 or STATUS_CARRIED_ID=92, the one that happens first
3. And the same for the other Carriers...

Comment: Why not create a side table containing relevant codes per carrier and then join on it

Comment: Aside... `WITH (NOLOCK)` is a code smell. Unless you fully understand the risks and impacts of using it you probably want to avoid it.